# Код не воспроизводится

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>2.1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center" > Пять событий с мышкой </h1>
    <p id="line1" onclick="m_click()">Щелкните по мне мышкой</p>
    <p id="line2" onmousedown="m_down()" onmouseup="m_up()">На этом тексте, подержите и отпустите кнопку</p>
    <p id="line3" onmouseenter="m_enter()" onmouseleave="m_leave()">Медленно проведите курсором по этой записи</p>
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" src="joban.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

joban.js:

```js
    flag=true;
    function m_click()
    {
      var line1 = document.getElementByld("line1");
      if (flag)
      {
        flag=false
        line1.style.background="aqua";
        line1.style.color="white";
        line1.style.fontSize = "48pt";
      }
      else
      {
      flag=true
      line1.style.background="white";
      line1.style.color="black";
      line1.style.fontSize = "12pt";
      }
    }
    function m_down()
    {
      document.getElementByld("line2").style.background="green";
    }
    function m_up()
    {
      document.getElementByld("line2").style.background="yellow";
    }
    function m_enter()
    {
      document.getElementByld("line3").style.background="red";
    }
    function m_leave()
    {
      document.getElementByld("line3").style.background="aqua";
    }
```

Comment: после html это joban.js

Answer (score 2):

Ну для начала неплохо было бы исправить опечатку в `getElementByld`. Там вместо `i` буква `l`

Правильное написание: `getElementById`

Comment: где именно, у меня вроде все правильно

Comment: @DenisDönitz, внимательнее проверяй.

Comment: Я все-равно не вижу

Comment: @DenisDönitz "где именно" - везде.

Comment: все, понел принел, спасибо, теперь работает

Comment: @DenisDönitz Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.